# Using ping class in blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I want to try to ping some device using Ping class in blazor webassembly project. I created code like bellow. When I am trying to debug my application it always finish executing at the first line without executing ping.send method. It's possible to make operations like this in browser by using this technology?

```
@page "/test"
@using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
@using System.Text;

<link href="~/css/" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PingDevice">Click me</button>
</form>


@code {


    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void PingDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("192.168.0.1", timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                currentCount = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                currentCount = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

     
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to try to ping some device using Ping class in blazor webassembly
> project

I do not think that can be done. Period.

See, in order to do that, you need a socket. Which is not something you can open out of web assembly. In order to make a real ping, you must get out ICMP packets (and get the reply). That is simply not doable in a browser.

https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1251

indicates so...

"However, even though you can use existing C/C++ APIs, it will internally use WebSockets for the connection, so your server must accept WebSockets. And WebSockets are TCP only."

That makes it impossible to use PING, and the PING classes.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/technical-due-diligence-wasm-ian-eyberg/

indicates this too.

"First off, WASM doesn't do raw sockets. WASM uses websockets which are TCP only but even that means that you can't produce your own TCP - you must use websockets."

and

"Raw sockets will never be implemented because it's such a huge security issue."

You can do that with server side BLAZOR (because on the server you run as .NET app), but not webassembly from the browser.

Anyone with other info - please correct me.